# Как реализовать автомасштабируемость для lineTo и moveTo, при изменении размеров окна, не трогая остальные виджеты?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5

Как реализовать автомасштабируемость для `lineTo` и `moveTo`, при изменении размеров окна, не трогая остальные виджеты?

Мой код:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QGridLayout, QSplitter, QHBoxLayout, QFrame, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPainterPath
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

width = 700
height = 550

# TODO Поменять коорд
line = [
    [(140, 140), (570, 525)],  # , (70, 100)
    [(20, 20), (350, 525), (100, 300), (600, 20)]
]

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        global width, height
        self.setGeometry(680, 400, width, height)
        self.setWindowTitle('Trajectory')
        bt_1 = QPushButton("New", self)
        bt_1.move(10, 10)

        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.drawLine(qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawLine(self, qp):
        path = QPainterPath()

        def draw_trajectory(trajectory):
            for i, (x, y) in enumerate(trajectory):
                if i == 0:
                    path.moveTo(x, y) #if i == 0 else path.lineTo(x, y)
                else:
                    path.lineTo(x, y)

        for trajectory in line:
            draw_trajectory(trajectory)

            qp.drawPath(path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Домножайте все координаты на коэффициент размера окна

Comment: Точнее, если соотношение сторон может меняться произвольно, то у вас должно быть 2 коэффициента: по-ширине и по-высоте окна

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Практический это может выглядеть так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QGridLayout, QSplitter, QHBoxLayout, QFrame, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPainterPath
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, line):
        super().__init__()
        self.widthApp, self.heightApp  = 700, 550                 # +++
        self.w, self.h = self.width(), self.height()              # +++
        self.line = line                                          # +++
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
#        global width, height
        self.setGeometry(580, 100, self.widthApp, self.heightApp)
        self.setWindowTitle('Trajectory')
        bt_1 = QPushButton("New", self)
        bt_1.move(10, 10)
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.drawLine(qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawLine(self, qp):
        path = QPainterPath()

        def draw_trajectory(trajectory):
            self.kw = round(self.width()/self.widthApp, 2)        # <---
            self.kh = round(self.height()/self.heightApp, 2)      # <---

            for i, (x, y) in enumerate(trajectory):
                if i == 0:
                    path.moveTo(x * self.kw, y * self.kh)         # +++
                else:
                    path.lineTo(x * self.kw, y * self.kh)         # +++

        for trajectory in self.line:
            draw_trajectory(trajectory)
            qp.drawPath(path)

# TODO Поменять коорд
line = [
    [(140, 140), (570, 525)],  # , (70, 100)
    [(20, 20), (350, 525), (100, 300), (600, 20)]
]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow(line)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `self.kw = round(self.width()/self.widthApp, 2)`
Что обозначает 2 в скобках?

Comment: round(number[, ndigits]) - округляет число number до ndigits знаков после запятой (по умолчанию, до нуля знаков, то есть, до ближайшего целого). Оно здесь не очень и нужно. Замените на чтобы не смущало: `self.kw = self.width()/self.widthApp` и `self.kh = self.height()/self.heightApp`